# What is the initial ModelView Matrix in opengl and by what calls it gets modified and how?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am programming in Android with OpenGL ES 1. The problem is that i would like to touch different objects in the scene. I want to try the ray pick method from this site.

http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm

However using ray pick i will have to multiply the ray vector with the inverse of the ModelView matrix. But using the Java APIs it is not possible to get any Matrix like with `glGetFloatv` in C Code. So the plan is to manage a ModelView matrix on my own and use it for ray picking.

The question is. How does the ModelView Matrix looks like initially? And by what calls it gets modified and how?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? *"using the Java APIs it is not possible to get any Matrix like with glGetFloatv in C Code"* `glGetFloatv` exists for Java/OpenGLES just like with C/OpenGL.

Comment: No. The Methods of Renderer (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html) get a GL10 (http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html) Object as a parameter. This object has no `glGetFloatv` method.